# Why is the $n$'th derivative of $(x-a_1)(x-a_2)\cdots (x-a_n)$ equal to $n!$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, chain-rule

$a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_n$ are any real numbers.

Using the product and chain rules doesn't seem to work well. Thanks.

Comment: The expression is a polynomial $x^n-(a_1+\cdots+a_n)x^{n-1}+ \cdots $ . Apart from the first term, all the terms are below order $x^n$. When you differentiate $n$ times all these terms will be killed & only the very first term will survive $ \frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^n) = n! $.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit You murderer.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri ... Sorry the terms will differentiate to zero & quietly go away ... $  \ddot \smile$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let : $$p(x)= (x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3) \cdots (x-a_n)$$

On multiplying all the brackets, you'll get :

$$p(x) = x^n-b_0x^{n-1} + \dots + b_{n-2}x+ b_{n-1} $$

Where $b_i$s are some constants.
$$p^1(x) = n(x)^{n-1} -(n-1) \cdot b_0x^{n-2} + \dots + b_{n-2}+0 $$

So on..

$$p^n(x)= n(n-1)(n-2) \cdots 3\cdot 2\cdot 1 \cdot x^0 = n!$$

Here $p^i(x)$ denotes $i^\text{th}$ derivative of $p(x)$.

Comment: Oh, it's just an $n$'th degree polynomial, which means its $n$'th derivative is $n!$.

Comment: @user263326 Yes, absolutely!

Comment: I mean a monic $n$'th degree polynomial.

Comment: It is somewhat conventional to write $p^{(i)}(x)$ rather than $p^i(x)$ in this context. $\qquad$